# How do I fetch query results with multiple criteria?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this

```
Table
-----
userid
fieldid
fieldvalue
```

where userid and fieldid are the primary key pair for this table.

I want to make an sql query that finds all users that have `fieldvalue` equal to something for a selected `fieldid`

For example, for the values

```
fieldid: 817
fieldvalue: 'yes'
```

I can have an sql query like:

```
select userid FROM table where (fieldid=817 AND fieldvalue='yes')
```

This query works fine.

However if i have a second or a third criterion, making the query
like this:

```
select userid 
FROM table 
where (fieldid=817 AND fieldvalue='yes')
AND (fieldid=818 AND fieldvalue='no')
```

returns an empty result but the conditions are satisfied in the
individual criterion.

Is there any way to correct this ?

#### update

i forgot to write down a use case (appologies)

```
userid, fieldid, fieldvalue
1 , 817, yes
1, 818, no
1, 825, yes 
2, 817, yes 
2, 818, yes
3, 829, no
```

for this table i want an sql query that finds the users that have the following conditions satisfied : The fieldid 817 has a value of yes and the fieldid 818 a value of no

Using the OR suggestions i had so far satisfied either the fieldid 817 to have a value of yes OR the fieldid 818 to have a value of no

I want both conditions to be satisfied. In the above the expected result will be

```
userid
1
```

and not

```
userid
1
2
```

Since userid 2 doesn't satisfy both conditions. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: You have to replace the AND between the brackets through an OR. Otherwise you want to select an entry with id=817 AND id=818.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an `OR` between your different criteria.

```
SELECT userid 
FROM table 
WHERE (fieldid=817 AND fieldvalue='yes')
    OR (fieldid=818 AND fieldvalue='no')
```

The difference between using `AND/OR`

> The AND operator displays a record if both the first condition and the
>   second condition is true.
>
> The OR operator displays a record if either the first condition or the
>   second condition is true.

EDIT: Based on your comments you can do it the following way

```
select t1.userid 
FROM temp t1
where (t1.fieldid=817 AND t1.fieldvalue='yes') 
    AND EXISTS (SELECT userid 
            FROM temp t 
            WHERE t.userid =  t1.userid 
                AND fieldid=818 
                AND fieldvalue='no')
```

see a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/06db1/1) with a working copy

or even this way

```
select t1.userid 
FROM temp t1
left join temp t2
    on t1.userid = t2.userid
where (t1.fieldid=817 AND t1.fieldvalue='yes')
    AND t2.fieldid=818 AND t2.fieldvalue='no'
```

here is another [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/06db1/2)

if you had more fields that you wanted to join on, then you would do the following:

```
select t1.userid 
FROM temp t1
left join temp t2
    on t1.userid = t2.userid
left join temp t3
    on t1.userid = t3.userid
where (t1.fieldid=817 AND t1.fieldvalue='yes')
    AND (t2.fieldid=818 AND t2.fieldvalue='no')
    AND (t3.fieldid=819 AND t3.fieldvalue='no')
```

Comment: Hi, but does this satisfy the condition that the fieldid=817 for this user will have a value of 'yes' AND fieldid=818 will have a value of 'no' ? I want both conditions to be satisfied and AND doesn't work for me so far

Comment: did you try running to see if it satisfies your requirements?

Comment: yes and it doesn't, it shows the users that either satisfy the first or the second condition

Comment: can you post some sample data and the expected result that you need?

Comment: hi i made a clarification, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Hi, that's correct, but in case you have more than 2 conditions to satisfy is self join the same solution ?

Comment: if you have more conditions, then you will need to alter the query to include the additional ones

Comment: @bluefeed 
Would it be right then if i write the following ? 

SELECT userid
FROM table AS t1 JOIN table AS t2 JOIN table AS t3 USING (userid)
WHERE
      (t1.fieldid = '817' AND t1.fieldvalue = 'yes')
  AND (t2.fieldid = '818' AND t2.fieldvalue = 'no' )
  AND (t3.fieldid = '819' AND t3.fieldvalue = 'no' )

Comment: yes, you would have include additional joins for each condition, see my edit

Answer (score 0):

Try using OR

```
select userid FROM table where (fieldid=817 AND fieldvalue='yes') OR(fieldid=818 AND fieldvalue='no')
```

Your query wanted the fieldid to be 817 and 818 which isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `OR` not `AND` in your `WHERE` clause. Check out this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp) for a quick-and-easy explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please try `OR` in Place of `AND`

```
select userid FROM table where (fieldid=817 AND fieldvalue='yes') OR (fieldid=818 AND fieldvalue='no')
```

If you use `AND`  then it will check if both conditions `fieldid=817 AND fieldvalue='yes'` ANd  `fieldid=818 AND fieldvalue='no'` must be fulfilled but it is not possible. ANd when you will use `OR` operator between both conditions then it will give result having both conditions ..

thanks

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the many suggestions of using `OR`, which are entirely correct, you could also use `IN` (which might make the query more readable if it scales).

```
SELECT userid FROM table WHERE (fieldid, fieldvalue) IN (
  (817, 'yes'),
  (818, 'no' )
);
```

---

To find all `userid` that satisfy **both** conditions, you need to self-join `table` to itself:

```
SELECT userid
FROM table AS t1 JOIN table AS t2 USING (userid)
WHERE
      (t1.fieldid = '817' AND t1.fieldvalue = 'yes')
  AND (t2.fieldid = '818' AND t2.fieldvalue = 'no' )
```

Comment: Hi this, will show only users that satisfy only one of the conditions and not both of them, is there an alternative with this notation ?

Comment: @nkorf: Are you saying that the same `userid` appears multiple times in your table, with different `(fieldid, fieldvalue)` pairs?  In that case, you need to self-join.  I have updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Hi, how can this work with 3 or more conditions ? is it right to write
FROM table AS t1 JOIN table AS t2 JOIN table AS t3 .... USING (userid)

Comment: @nkorf: You must instruct MySQL how to join each additional table:  `FROM table AS t1 JOIN table AS t2 USING (userid) JOIN table AS t3 USING (userid) ...`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use it like:

```
select userid 
FROM table 
where fieldid in (817, 818) and fieldvalue in ('yes', 'no');
```

Comment: This would also match on `(817, 'no')` and `(818, 'yes')`, which are not desirable.